# How to sort rows between time A (in format "hh:mm:ss")and time B using awk shell script (like below?)?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

I want to sort rows between `time A` and `time B` in format `"00:00:00"` using awk shell script like (by just comparing the time columns of time directly) :

```
awk '{
        if ("15:21:14" <= $1 && $1 <= "15:51:14")
        {print $0}
     }'
```

I got the right rows, but is it absolutely right for me to do this?
***If not, what is the right way?***

Comment: This will select the rows in the given interval, because the time ordering in this format corresponds with the lexicographic ordering of strings. However, it won't sort the output.

Comment: @Simon, so if the time doesn't appear in the format, the code won't work. But if never, it is OK.

Comment: @Rubby wrt `...using awk shell script...`. awk is not shell and vice-versa, they are 2 separate tools. You can invoke one from the other so you can have a shell script call an awk script or an awk script call a shell script, just like you can have a shell script call a C program or a C program call a shell script. Thinking awk and shell are the same will get you into trouble down the road.

Comment: Why dont you just pipe the rows selected by the awk script to `sort`?  I.e. like `awk '...' < file | sort`

Comment: i would point out, your question title mentioned "sort rows". if those rows are not sorted in your input file. the output is not sorted either. You just did the "pick" part, not the "sort". however, if rows are already sorted in your input file. there is no problem. Also you need to be careful about the time. if there is a Date before the time, say `2000-10-10 22:23:00` your awk will return the time periods for all days.

Comment: @TerjeD. awk can sort too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming when you said "...I want to sort rows..." you really meant you want to SELECT rows, here's how to write that in awk:

```
awk '("15:21:14" <= $1) && ($1 <= "15:51:14")' file
```

This will work as long as all of your timestamps follow the same format and use a full 2 digits for every number, padding single-digit hours, for example, with a leading zero. If you want to sort the result then pipe the output to sort:

```
awk '("15:21:14" <= $1) && ($1 <= "15:51:14")' file | sort
```